# How to Group repeated lines into one variable and print the second line after each using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Using python, I want to read through a JSONs, and find lines that start with the same word, and only show the last word in the line. Then store these repeated lines into one variable, so when I say print, the lines will only print once instead the number of times they repeat. And following this variable of groups, print part of the line that is 2 lines after the repeated line.

That most likely didn't make any sense. Lol.

**So, here's the code I have so far:**

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    if line.strip().startswith('"ID":'):
        try:
            name_line = lines[i+2]
            print line[21:-2]
        except StopIteration:
            break
        print name_line[15:-2]
        print '\n'
```

**Sample text file** 
(I want to group lines that start with the ID field and print the second line that follows (the name line))

```
{
      "theme": land1,
      "ID": "biosphere",
      "Url": "www.land.com",
      "name": "mangrove",
    },
    {
      "theme: water1,<br>
      "ID": "hydrosphere",<br>
      "Url": "www.water.com",<br>
      "name": "Pacific",<br>
    },
    {
      "theme": "air1,
      "ID": "atmosphere",
      "Url": "www.air.com",
      "name": "Oxygen",
    },
    {
     "theme": land2,
      "ID": "biosphere",
      "Url": "www.land.com",
      "name": "oak",<
    },
    {
      "theme: water2,
      "ID": "hydrosphere",
      "Url": "www.water.com",
      "name": "Atlantic",
    },
    {
      "theme": "air2,
      "ID": "atmosphere",
      "Url": "www.air.com",
      "name": "Nitrogen",
    },
}
```

**My Current Output:**

```
biosphere
mangrove

hydrosphere
Pacific


atmosphere
Oxygen

biosphere
oak

hydrosphere
Atlantic

atmosphere
Nitrogen
```

**The Output I Want:**

```
biosphere
mangrove
oak

hydrosphere
Pacific
Atlantic

atmosphere
Oxygen
Nitrogen
```

Is this possible? Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you cannot parse your data as json?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSON, but I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use JSON do something like that should work:

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
myDict = {}
for line in f:
    if line.strip().startswith('"ID":'):
        key = line.split('"')[3]
    if line.strip().startswith('"name":'):
        value = line.split('"')[3]
        myDict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)


for key in myDict:
    print key
    print '\n'.join(myDict[key])
    print
```

Comment: Hi Fred! This works perfectly. Thanks so much! However, I don't understand the code. Do you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: Hi @afrocodes, sure: `.split('"')` splits the line at each `"` and returns a list. `[3]` takes the 4th element of the list (biosphere, or mangrove for instance).

Comment: `myDict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)` is like `d[key]=d[key].append(value)` exepts that if `d[key]` is not defined, it returns `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it as JSON file rather than text file.

You can easily modify JSON files and fetch values depending on matching keys and aggregate them.

Comment: Just come to know that it looks more like dict than json, I suggest just look at sample dict and json example to get brief idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a list of dictionaries rather than lines of text to be parsed.  Import the file as json and then loop through each item in your list, grabbing each element you need to make a dictionary of your own.

and you may have to take out those "<br>" statements before you start.

Comment: I only added the "<br>" statements because it was the only way to break up my lines on separate lines. I'll work on looking more into dictionaries.